# How can i show drill down records in SSRS email subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a report which has drill down option ,when i subscribe that report to my email,i am unable to see the drill down records.Do i need to change any settings in order to display the drill down ?
thanks in advance

Comment: In which format do you render the Report when sending by email? Have you tried to consider Excel format? It will show the drill down records using the Excel row grouping.

Comment: Got it, when i changed the format to Excel it is working